# Purpose of empty System.out.println()

Tags: java, println, system.out

I have the following code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

it prints out a star pattern

```
*
**
***
****
```

What is the purpose of `System.out.println();`? Why do we put it at the end of the loop?

Comment: It's not rocket science, run with and without, you should be able to see the difference.

Comment: `println()` performs 2 actions: move to new line and print.  When you do nit give it anything to print it just moved to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Just to print out a "\n" (move to the next line).
Strange question...

Comment: Note that the choice of the line separator depends on the system. `println` is platform independent and will pick `\r\n` on Windows (more specifically, it uses `System.lineSeparator()`)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

`print("*")` only prints stars in the **current line**.

But at some point you have to finish the current line and move on to the next line. That is what `println()` does (**ln** stands for **line**).

So without the `System.out.println()` you will get everything in a single line:

```
**********
```

And with it you get multiple lines:

```
*
**
***
****
```

---

### `println` vs `print`

`println` behaves more or less identical to `print` with a newline symbol (`\n` or `\r\n`), so:

```
System.out.println(foo);

// behaves the same as

System.out.print(foo + System.lineSeparator());
```

You can see the exact details in the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L889).